# First example in dummies guide has error : NameError: name GPIO is not defined

Tags: gpio

Raspberry Pi for Dummies. Page 49

Line 7
   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

error:
NameError: name GPIO is not defined

we've checked it's definately the letter 'O' not a zero.
Either the code isn't right or the import RPi.GPIO isn't correct.

`we tried python and python3

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the code you are attempting to run together with the actual error message (cut & paste).

Comment: Hi Jack :) Welcome to Pi Q&A - Technically - If one of the answers, answered your question - you should have up voted it and accepted it (I understand you may not have had enough rep to accept it - I don't get that but yea) Please accept an answer if you can.. and don't be shy with up votes :D Good luck and see you around.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what the full example looks like but ti should look like this.

```
#external module imports
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#pin setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
```

Comment: the issue was `as GPIO` missing. Thanks, it works now!

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing all your code, so I'm not sure what you have imported, however, after doing

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

the statement

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
```

should work. If you forgot the `as GPIO` part, it would still work but you'd have to type

```
RPi.GPIO.setmode(RPi.GPIO.BCM)
```